# SQL IN equivalent in elastic with a subQuery to fetch Data

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a Elastic Document which is in following hierarchy

```
Department: [{
       Employee: [{
            Projects: []
    }]
  }]
```

The documents are at a project level.

I want a list of all the projects per employee based on the latest project the employee is working on when I pass in the Department.

I am trying to do a equivalent of SQL In query in Elastic.

```
Select top 1 from Project where employee_id in (select employee_id from department where department_code='Dept')
```

I am using elastic 7.17.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of nested aggregations, filters, and sorting.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "Department.Employee",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            { "match": { "Department.department_code": "Dept" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "employees": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "Department.Employee"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_project": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": [{ "Department.Employee.Project.date": { "order": "desc" }}]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```